# Why doesn't `iframe` auto margin center the iframe inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` and an `iframe` inside it. I want to make the iframe to be center. The `margin: auto` works for other dom but not the iframe. Is there a way for me to center the iframe inside the div?

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

iframe {
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <iframe src="http://localhost:8080" align="right" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps because `marign` is misspelled?

Comment: sorry, I have a typo and I have corrected it in the question. It is still not working.

Comment: it's perfectly centred as you can see in the snippet I created, so check if there is more CSS

Comment: oh, you are right. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important;` to your iframe css tag

```
iframe {
  margin: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).